# Python SSH server (socket + paramiko) "Address already in use"

Tags: python, sockets, ssh

So I decided to read more about networks in Python, and in the book I'm reading, there's this piece of code that creates a SSH server using paramiko (a third party SSH module) and socket.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I input a server address, it says "Address already in use". In addition, I'm already using `sock.setsockopt(sock.SOL_SOCKET, sock.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` so the address can be reused, but the problem still persists.

Here's the full code:

```
import socket
import paramiko
import threading
import sys
import traceback

# using the key from the Paramiko demo files
host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='test_rsa.key')

class Server (paramiko.ServerInterface):

    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind=='session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED

    def check_auth_password(self,user, password):
        if (usernae == 'matheus') and (password ==  'password'):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

server = sys.argv[1]
ssh_port = int(sys.argv[2])

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((server, ssh_port))
    sock.listen(100) # Wow so many connections
    print ("[+] Listening for connection ...")
    client, addr = sock.accept()

except Exception, e:
    print("[-] Listen failed: " + str(e))
    traceback.print_stack()
    sys.exit(1)

print("[+] Got a connection!") # runs as except exits


try:
    bhSession = paramiko.Transport(client)
    bhSession.add_server_key(host_key)
    server = Server()


    try:
        bhSession.start_server(server=server)
    except paramiko.SSHException, x:
        print("[-] SSH negotiation failed.")

    chan = bhSession.accept(20)
    print("[+] Authenticated!")
    print(chan.recv(1024))
    chan.send("Welcome to bh_ssh")

    while True:
        try:
            command = raw_input("Enter command: ").strip('\n')
            if command != 'exit':
                chan.send(command)
                print(chan.recv(1024)+'\n')
            else:
                chan.send('exit')
                print("exiting") 
                bhSession.close()
                raise Exception("exit")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            bhSession.close()

except Exception, e:
    print("[-] Caught exception: " + str(e))
    try:
        bhSession.close()
    except:
        pass
    sys.exit(1)
```

The addresses I've tried are:

```
192.168.1.107 (current device address)
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 (localhost)
```

The port was always 22.

Peace!

Comment: doesn't sshd already listen on port 22 on your server?

Comment: try netstat -laputen and see what is listening on port 22, or change your port in your code.

Comment: I think I opened port 22 the other day for SSH actually, could that be the problem?

Comment: Output of nmap on my address:  '22/tcp   open   ssh'

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option before binding the socket.

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SO_REUSEPORT` is what most people would expect `SO_REUSEADDR` to be.

Basically, `SO_REUSEPORT` allows you to bind an arbitrary number of sockets to exactly the same source address and port as long as all prior bound sockets also had `SO_REUSEPORT` set before they were bound.